# VB.NET How to change textbox from a thread of another class?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I search google very very many times and I know my question is very old but I still can't change my textbox from a thread of another class, have not error and have not any change of textbox, please help me to show `dataFromClientOfDoChat` to textbox

My problem at line 71-72 (which line i commented near bottom)
My code have a textbox is txtContent

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Public Class Server
    Dim clientsList As New Hashtable
    Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim clNo As String

    Private Sub Server_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        serverSocket.Start()

        msg("Chat Server Started ....")

        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Main)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        While True
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()

            Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
            Dim dataFromClient As String

            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
            clientsList(dataFromClient) = clientSocket
            msg(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ")

            clNo = dataFromClient
            Dim client As New HandlerClient
            client.StartClient(clientSocket)
        End While

        clientSocket.Close()
        serverSocket.Stop()
        msg("exit")

    End Sub
    Private Sub msg(ByVal text As String)
        txtContent.Text = txtContent.Text + text + Environment.NewLine
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class HandlerClient
    Public clientSocket As New TcpClient
    Public Sub StartClient(ByVal clSocket As TcpClient)
        Me.clientSocket = clSocket
        Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
        ctThread.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub doChat()
        Dim requestCount As Integer
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        Dim dataFromClientOfDoChat As String
        Dim rCount As String
        While True
            Try
                Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
                dataFromClientOfDoChat = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
                dataFromClientOfDoChat = dataFromClientOfDoChat.Substring(0, dataFromClientOfDoChat.IndexOf("$"))

                '  Server.txtContent.Text = ("From client - " + "clNo " + " : " + dataFromClientOfDoChat) ' this line not work

                MsgBox("From client - " + "clNo " + " : " + dataFromClientOfDoChat) 'And this line work
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't, not directly anyway.  The text box as thread affinity to the main UI thread, and only that can update. I suggest you instead have some kind of messaging or eventing mechanism that tells the textbox owning class to update accordingly, doing so on its own thread.

Comment: Can you tell me, What I have to do?Use Delegate, RaiseEvent or...

Comment: That's for you to decide upon, based on your overall architecture etc.  But yes, using events is certainly one possibility, or you could go for something less tightly coupled. Besides, in this case where you are using sockets, you need to think about just posting a message back to the server socket instead.   Just because your code is together, the client and server are communicating over sockets, so events won't work.  You are just posing messages between the server and the client, and you need to use that to communicate between the two

Comment: I understand you, I've tried It out "class" and i can put DataFromClient to TextBox but my threads not running good so i have to put code for client to a class